# What is difference here - @Autowired and @MockBean

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I was writing unit tests for our services classes in spring boot project. Where tests were properly running when I'am autowiring the class which am testing and it fails when I use @MockBean insead of @Autowire.

```
@SpringBootTest
class SignupServiceTest {

  @Autowired SignupService signupService;

  @MockBean DSService dsService;

  @MockBean SignupHelper signupHelper;

  @MockBean SessionHelper sessionHelper;

  @MockBean CommonService commonService;
```

Can somehelp help me with difference and why @MockBean is failing. Also is there a way to mock methods of autowired class(Current class) in mockito.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A @SpringBootTest is a test that actually starts up a Spring container along with the beans of the application.

@Autowired fields in tests behave like they do in normal Spring-Beans; they get injected with the actual beans configured in the application (xml, @Bean in a @Configuration, or @Component/@Service).

@MockBean creates a mock that they behave like normal mocks that you can control with `when/then` etc and check with `verify` and suchlike. The thing that is special about them is that they get injected into other beans in the context (for instance when you call `Mockito.initAnnotations(this)`).